# Ideas for basic web applications in JavaScript for learning purposes

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-applications

I am looking for ideas on small projects in JavaScript to deepen my learning. The internet either has To-do lists (very simple) or Twitter clone (very hard). I know basic JavaScript & jQuery, and am looking for a manageable challenge as well as something that will help me practice basic skills.

Comment: Think something you would like or find useful, depends a lot on your hobbies.

Comment: Totally inappropriate question for this site. We do not offer ideas for projects, career or educational advice, or other non-specific questions. This site is for specific questions about actual problems you are facing with code or a programmers tool. The question should be able to be answered by a single post that can be accepted as correct. You've asked for a list of suggestions, which is not acceptable here. You should take some time to go through the [tour] and read through the [help] pages to familiarize yourself with the types of question that are appropriate to ask here.

Comment: maybe tic-tac-toe to improve your 2D array skills ;)

Comment: As @KenWhite mentioned SO is not the site for this kind of questions. Anyways, why not try a hard project? Those are the ones that truly make you learn new things

Comment: @KenWhite apologies, still learning the site. Tried to remove the question but didn't allow. Thanks for the advice

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Quiz Application...**

(Simple) You create quiz in javascript with questions about javascript, you learn on both sides...

**Memorable Cards**

(Too Simple) Card have two sides, one question, one has the answer

**TodoList for Multiple Users**

Task manager with timer and multiple user support

**Rich Text Editor**

You know i.e. something I can use BBCode or something similar inside to style comments or whatever...

**WYSIWYG Editor for HTML**

Just to examine drag and drop capabilities of javascript...

***Music Aplication***

Software synthetizer using some javascript library...

***Image Aplication***

Some editor you can crop images in...

Answer (score -1):

creating a paint application is fun.

see https://paintAppmp.herokuapp.com